# window.MathJax is undefined in Firefox, works in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a Chrome/Firefox extension in inject [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) 3.0.1 into arbitrary web pages, [Green Pi](https://github.com/nschloe/green-pi/). It's working well for Chrome, but I'm having trouble with Firefox.

The `content_script.js` is

```js
MathJax = {  
  chtml: {  
    fontURL: chrome.runtime.getURL("fonts"),  
  },  
};  
require("mathjax-full/components/src/tex-chtml/tex-chtml.js"); 

// This paints pages green
// require("green.js");
// // cat green.js == document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

(It's getting a little more involved when the user opts in/out of certain pages, but this isn't relevant here.)

Now, as noted in the code, the above works fine in Chrome, but fails in Firefox with the MathJax error

```
MathJax(?): window.MathJax is undefined
```

I don't see any other warning or error. Any hint on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you check [Chrome incompatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#tabs_incompatibilities)?

Comment: Sounds like MathJax may have a bug when running as a content script in Firefox. Try adding `debugger` in mathjax.js and open devtools on the injected tab, then try stepping through the code. A simpler test might be to declare mathjax in `content_scripts` for easier debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've checked the incompatibilities, they don't seem related. Stepping through mathjax appears impractical because of the size and complication of the library. This is a tough nut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a MathJax bug after all, cf. https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2399.